# VBA Macro not working on French excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a macro for my French counterparts, and it doesn't seem to want to work. I understand there are some functions that need to be changed, eg LEN becomes NBCAR (according to the website I found). After doing this it errors saying "Sub or function not defined" (in French) whilst highlighting NBCAR. In my version of the macro, LEN is not defined so its slightly frustrating. Is there a quick fix, perhaps a way to tell VBA to read the code in English?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Code from my English Macro:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, N As Long
Dim st As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim sPath As String
Set sh1 = Sheets("VTR - MASTER")
Dim R As Integer
Dim Z As Range
Dim VTR As String
Dim W As Integer
R = 1
W = 1
VTR = Sheets("VTR - INFO").Range("J1").Value

MsgBox "Select Destination To Save ORT CSV", vbInformation, "Select Destination"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        sPath = .SelectedItems(1)

' Filter Merchant ID

MERCHID = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To MERCHID
    v = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    If v <> "" Then
        st = st & v & ","
    End If
Next i
st = Mid(st, 1, Len(st) - 1)
Arr1 = Split(st, ",")

Sheets("VTR - DATA").Select
Sheets("VTR - DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
With Sheets("VTR - DATA").Range("A:Q")
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "<>SOR"
    End With


Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:G,K:L"))
rng1.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Sheets("CSV").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("VTR - DATA").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: I remember that problem!! A big design flaw in Excel IMO.

Comment: @simoco   Code now included.. Thank you!

Comment: not sure why it's not working in French, in general _VBA functions_ should always be the same (but _worksheet functions_ can differ in differenf languages). But you can try to change `st = Mid(st, 1, Len(st) - 1)` to this one: `st = Evaluate("STXT(" & st & "; 1; NBCAR(" & st & ") - 1)")` or `st = Evaluate("STXT(" & st & ", 1, NBCAR(" & st & ") - 1)")` - depends on regional French separator (whether it's comma or semicolon)

Comment: Btw, `I understand there are some functions that need to be changed, eg LEN becomes NBCAR` - it's not true. VBA should be the same for every language. `NBCAR` is french euqivalent of _worksheet function_ `Len`, i.e. if your _cell_ (but not VBA code) contains formula in english excel `=Len(A1)`, in french it should be `=NBCAR(A1)`. But in VBA code you should use for both languages `Len`

Comment: Thanks for your help, will give it a go and let you know.. Thanks!

Comment: Conditional compilation is an option if absolutely needed, but I suspect that Simoco's comment has the answer.

Comment: As already said you may be using some `WorksheetFunction` that need some attention, but I would also keep an eye to the `.FormulaLocal`s. Remember that you can always use the English notation with `.Formula`!

Comment: Also I suspect that the range rng1 is not well defined with Range("F:G,K:L") that might rather be : Range("F:G","K:L").

Comment: Try to change:
    `Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:G,K:L"))`
to >>>>>>>>>>>>
    `Set rng1 = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("F:G"),Range("K:L"))`

Comment: Make yourself a favor: please learn to indent your code properly. This is unreadable. You can install free Smart indenter to help: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/

Answer (score 1):

There is missing `End If` for:

```
If .SelectedItems.Count > 0
```

And `End With` for:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
```

After that it compiles OK. (Of course it does not run, because I do not have sheet with name "VTR - MASTER" and etc.)

If VBA editor shows an error by functions like `LEN` please check
missing references in menu Tools - References. Sometimes missing references confuses VBA that it shows an error even by internal functions.